# I finally broke the graphics in 18.04, please help

Tags: drivers, 18.04, graphics, intel-graphics

After trying to fix my graphics drivers I have finally come to a point where I get a black screen on boot, even though "nomodeset" is set in /etc/default/grub.

The system is a Thinkpad X1 carbon with an Intel HD 620 graphics card.

The full previous story is [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1209493/18-04-how-to-revert-to-original-video-intel-drivers), but to be short the thing is that Ubuntu was no longer loading the intel drivers but the system would boot and see fine but with some issues (brightness controls broken, not suspend on closing lid),  and in my attempt to fix things I did this:

```
sudo add-apt repository -y ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
```

After that I would see this:

[image: details]

Then I tried to force the intel drivers doing:

```
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04
sudo apt install xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
```

After this, I get a black screen on boot. I tried to undo it by

```
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-core-hwe-18.04
sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04
```

But I still get the black screen (again, I have "nomodeset" in the grub file).

Some help for fixing this enormous mess would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: It keeps getting better. Now I saw that all the `xserver-xorg-video-*` packages are gone, by doing `dpkg --get-selections | grep xserver-xorg-video` I only see `xserver-xorg-video-intel` and `xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-18.04`, both marked as `rc`.

EDIT2: Well, I managed to fix the black screen by doing 
`sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg`
However, still I get the 'llvmpipe' as the graphics in the Details window...

EDIT3:

IT IS FINALLY FIXED!!!!

After the last edit, I removed the 'nomodeset' from the GRUB file and it is finally working!
All the apparent issues are gone (brightness and suspend working again),
`lshw -C video` shows `configuration: driver=i915` and in the Settings window I see "Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2)"

Comment: I looked through your series of 4(?) questions and I'd sum up the situation by saying you started with a good state, then broke it by installing more and more packages, trying to remove them, adding ppas, etc. I read you don't want to but it really will be easier to reinstall the system than try to untangle this. I hope you have solid backups. After you reinstall consider adding some utilities that can help in future like aptik and timeshift.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. I am trying to avoid reinstalling for 2 resons: 1) it is a dual-boot system and I have some concerns about screwing up the windows partition in the process; and 2) it would be quite time-consuming to compile again all the packages, programs, etc etc. So before giving up, I am trying my best to recover the system. After all, I think it should be "simply" a matter of getting the proper drivers again, right?

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. Before trying `wine` again, consider installing `timeshift` which lets you roll your system back to a known good state.